# Let $\tau=\{(-\infty,a)\ :\ a\in\mathbb{R}\}\cup\{\emptyset, \mathbb{R}\}.$Does $\{\frac{1}{n}\}_n$ converge or diverge in this topology.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology

Let $\tau=\{(-\infty,a)\ :\ a\in\mathbb{R}\}\cup\{\emptyset, \mathbb{R}\}.$ Discuss the convergence or divergence of $\{\frac{1}{n}\}_n$ in this topology.

If $\{\frac{1}{n}\}_n$  converges to $p$, $\forall (W \in \tau, W \ni p) \ \exists N \in \mathbb{N} : \forall n \geq N \ p_n \in W$. Other than that... I am unsure on how to provide a formal proof. It seems intuitively obvious to me that the sequence converges to $0$, but is it enough to merely say that the sequence enters into any open set that contains $0$?

Answer (score 2):

Let $p$ be a point in $\mathbb{R}$. If $p < 0$, then $p \in (-\infty,0)$, and this set is open and contains no point of the sequence. So ...

If $p \ge 0$ and $p \in (-\infty, a)$, then $a > p \ge 0$, so for any $n \ge n_0 > \frac{1}{a}$ we have $\frac{1}{n} \le \frac{1}{n_0} < a$, so ...

Comment: So it converges to any $p\geq0$?

Comment: @SuzuHirose Indeed.

Comment: The sequence does not converge to $0$?

Comment: Hmm, I guess I am confusing "convergence" in analysis with the concept of limits in calculus. I can see now why Suzu is correct, thanks.

Comment: @CormanoSanchez it does converge to 0 but also to all larger points. In general topology limits of sequences need not be unique!